# Flutter - save json data local for a future list

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

So, my question is, i want to save a json data localy so the user can see his saved projects.

```
  Future saveData() async {
    SharedPreferences kitSalvos = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    kitSalvos.setString('id', id);
    kitSalvos.setString('content', content);
  }
```

The content is the json data.

This is what i am doing, but, when i try to create a list of it, it brings other sharedPreferences.

```
  _getDataKits() async {
    SharedPreferences kitSalvos = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print(kitSalvos.getKeys());
  }
```

Output:

```
{isLogged, senha, email, 20210408, 20210408040319, token, id, content}
```

I want to bring only the saved projects (which is the ID and CONTENT) sharedpreferences...

There is a way to make it separeted? So i can only get the ID and CONTENT...

Also, make it one, like and object:

```
 kitsalvos = [ id: ID, content: CONTENT ];
```

There will be more then 1 saved project, so i need to store all of it separeted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the JSON on string and when you have to use it, you can get the String and parse to a model.

Create this model:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final kitModel = kitModelFromMap(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

KitModel kitModelFromMap(String str) => KitModel.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String kitModelToMap(KitModel data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class KitModel {
KitModel({
    this.the20210408,
    this.isLogged,
    this.senha,
    this.email,
    this.the20210408040319,
    this.token,
    this.id,
    this.content,
});

String the20210408;
bool isLogged;
String senha;
String email;
String the20210408040319;
String token;
int id;
String content;

factory KitModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => KitModel(
    the20210408: json["20210408"],
    isLogged: json["isLogged"],
    senha: json["senha"],
    email: json["email"],
    the20210408040319: json["20210408040319"],
    token: json["token"],
    id: json["id"],
    content: json["content"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "20210408": the20210408,
    "isLogged": isLogged,
    "senha": senha,
    "email": email,
    "20210408040319": the20210408040319,
    "token": token,
    "id": id,
    "content": content,
    };
}
```

saving the kit ->

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('content', content);
```

getting the kit ->

```
dart:convert


SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String KitJson = prefs.getString("content");

if (KitJson != null) {
  kit = KitModel.fromMap(json.decode(KitJson));
}
```

now you can use

```
print({kit.id, kit.content, kit.toke, kit.isLogged}); //And so on
```